# デバッグシンボルのみのオブジェクトファイルの生成方法

Tags: c

```
gcc -g -o hello hello.c
```

でデバッグシンボル付きの実行可能なオブジェクトファイルhelloが生成されます。

```
objcopy --strip-debug hello
```

とすることで、デバッグシンボルなしなオブジェクトファイルになります。

ではデバッグシンボル**のみ**なオブジェクトファイルを生成するには、どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ strip --only-keep-debug [executable]
```

> `strip(1)`
>
> --only-keep-debug
>   　Strip a file, removing contents of any sections that would not be stripped by --strip-debug and leaving the debugging sections intact.

もしくは、

```
$ objcopy --only-keep-debug [executable] [output]
```